# Client Server Programming

Tags: c++, unix, client-server, serversocket, fork

- Here the code executes the required output perfectly
- It checks for the condition and prints the error if the condition is not true , but it also prints even if the condition is true and followed but the required output.
- finding problem in a small if else condition
- how it can corrected
- In the below code`if (fork() == 0)` &  `if (!request.compare("") == 0)` has no effect

  ```
  /* Loop forever */ 
  while (1) 
  {
  /* Accept a client connection */    
      clientFd = accept (serverFd, clientSockAddrPtr, (socklen_t*)&clientLen); 

  //Fork child
      //if (fork() == 0) 
      {
      while(1)
      {   //Reads the client
              string request = read_Request (clientFd); 
          bool found = false;
          string response="Error !!! Country not found"; 
          //if (!request.compare("") == 0) 
          {

              for(vector<Country>::iterator it = countryData.begin(); it != countryData.end(); it++)
              {
          if(request.compare(it -> name) == 0) 
          {   
          string countryName = it -> name; 
          response += "\n";               
          response += it -> name; 
          response += "'s TLD Code"; 
          response += ((countryName).append("'s TLD Code")); 
          response += ": ";
          response += it -> TLDCode; 
          response += "\n";

          countryName = it -> name;
          response += it -> name;
          response += "'s FIPS104 Country Code"; 
          response += ((countryName).append("'s FIPS104 Country Code")); 
          response += ": ";
          response += it -> FIPS104CountryCode; 
          response += "\n";

          countryName = it -> name;
          response += it -> name;
          response += "'s ISO2 Country Code"; 
          response += ((countryName).append("'s ISO2 Country Code")); 
          response += ": ";
          response += it -> ISO2CountryCode; 
          response += "\n";

          countryName = it -> name; 
          response += it -> name; 
          response += "'s population"; 
          response += ((countryName).append("'s population")); 
          response += ": ";
          response += it -> population; 
          response += "\n";


              found = true;

              }
          }
  }



  write (clientFd, response.c_str(), strlen (response.c_str()) + 1);  
      }
      }

          close (clientFd); 
  }
  ```

  }

[Here is the snip of output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J59k5.png)

> The string response is printed in case of both true and false.

Any suggestions please

Comment: Nothing in your code prints the string response.  It is incomplete.  ALso, this doesn't appear to be C: there is no string type in C.

Comment: @ChrisJ.Kiick , I have made changes to code .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay so here you assign a string to the variable `response`
    `String response="Error !!! Country not found";`

then here you concatinate other string to response, which gives you your output.

```
response += "\n";               
response += it -> name;
```

i.e. Error !!! Country not found + \n + it->name etc

Secondly as @ChrisJ.Kiick  said you have a mysterious String type which isnt a part of the c language